# Divi navigation on mobiles is not showing

Tags: wordpress, divi-theme

I'm customizing the already existing menu in my `Divi` theme, I use `QuadManu PRO` plugin to customize it.

When I customized my menu I noticed that it stopped displaying on mobiles, 
I checked HTML of the page and noticed there're no any HTML code which is responsible for the menu for mobiles, so I suppose my Divi theme doesn't even add that menu, it's like just turned off somewhere

Sorry guys, I'm not so skilled in that area and don't know how to get back mobile menu

Thank you very much for any ideas and answers))

Comment: Did you try to revert the changes and see if the menu appears again?

Comment: yes, just tried, it helped)) thanks